# Is it worth to make an O(1) function a coroutine in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have 2 functions, `Foo()` and `Bar()`.

Foo's time complexity is `θ(1)`, Bar's is `θ(n²)`, they execute one after the other respectively and Bar has no dependecies with Foo.

Is it worth to make Foo a coroutine to have some speedup?

Comment: O(1) says nothing about the speed of Foo(), it only says the speed is constant. For all that matters it could be that Foo() takes 10 secs to complete (always) and Bar() takes 1ms when n=1 and 10 secs when n=100, in which case you could get a speedup of 2x by running them in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it worth parallelizing? It depends. The trade-off here is between time performance and readibility / maintainability of your code.

I would only implement time performance improvements if necessary. First question you should ask, do you or the users notice a lag or bad performance? If no, then no need for optimizations.

Second step is to profile and measure. You should know which part of the code is critical. So for Foo() and Bar() you should measure how much time they take in a average and worst case. Then see how much time you can save. Then you need to decide is it worth it. ;)

Like mentioned in the comments the big O notation in general will not help you much there. Measure it!

Comment: Yeah, I kind of had the wrong idea here associating the big O notation with execution time. I'll profile the code and see if it's worth to parallelize. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Unity coroutines are still executed on main thread. One after another. Unless you are using something like "Thread Ninja - Multithread Coroutine" from asset store, you will not gain anything from coroutines.

Comment: I know nothing about Unity3d, and the OP's description made me assume that coroutines execute in parallel (otherwise there wouldn't be any speedup anyway as you point out). A quick read on Unity3d coroutines confirms your answer.